# Why is my manim scene being converted into a png instead of an mp4

Tags: python, manim

I have a python file that I am using to program a few scenes in manim. I looked over the Quick Start documentation, and everything works fine. But when I made another scene, called `ThreeSquares`, it converts the file into a black png. I have no idea what's going wrong, what should I do?

Code for the function:

```
from manim import *    

class ThreeSquares(Scene):
    def constructor(self):
        left_square = Square(color=BLUE, fill_opacity=0.7).shift(4 * LEFT)
        middle_square = Square(color=RED, fill_opacity=0.7)
        right_square = Square(color=GREEN, fill_opacity=0.7).shift(4 * RIGHT)
        self.play(Create(left_square), Create(middle_square), Create(right_square))
        self.play(Rotate(left_square, angle=PI), Rotate(right_square, angle=-1*PI), run_time=1)
        self.wait
```

I've tried running the command `manim -pql scene.py ThreeSquares` (scene.py is the file name), and that produced a black png.

I've also tried `python -m manim scene.py ThreeSquares -p -ql`, and that yielded the same result.

I've also tried to look in the documentation for any reason as to why this is happening, and I came up with nothing. I've also looked around on StackOverflow for this and there doesn't seem to be problems pertaining to this specific result.

Comment: `self.wait` must be called with parentheses: `self.wait()`. It is probably becoming an image because the animations don't have enough time to play and so it's only showing the first frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is very simple, you have written you logic in a function named `constructor` instead of `construct` in the **4rd line** which is what manim looks for to render the video. Please correct the function name and it should work.

```
class DifferentRotations(Scene):
def construct(self):
    left_square = Square(color=BLUE, fill_opacity=0.7).shift(2 * LEFT)
    right_square = Square(color=GREEN, fill_opacity=0.7).shift(2 * RIGHT)
    self.play(
        left_square.animate.rotate(PI), Rotate(right_square, angle=PI), run_time=2
    )
    self.wait()
```

Also add parentheses to like so `self.wait()` in the last line (this does not cause an error though). Hope this helps thankyou!

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to using python and manim, so I didn't know that it was looking for that